# Finite-dimensional unitary operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I need help in proving the following

> Let $A$ and $B$ be finite-dimensional unitary operators. Then either
> $$ {\left\|\left(\frac{A+B}{2} \right)^k\  \right\|}<1 $$
> for all $k \geq 1$ , or else for some vector $f \ne 0$ we have
> $Af=Bf; \ A^2f=ABf=BAf=B^2 f;\ A^3f=A^2Bf=ABAf=···=B^3f;\ ... $

I know that the norm of unitary operator is $1$,and if ${\left\|f+g  \right\|}={\left\|f  \right\|}+{\left\|g  \right\|}$ with ${\left\|f  \right\|}={\left\|g  \right\|}=1$ then $ f=g$ (the equality case of the triangle inequality ),but I cannot see the proof. If any one can help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left\|\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)^k\right\|\le\left\|\frac{A+B}{2}\right\|^k\le\left(\frac{\|A\|+\|B\|}{2}\right)^k=1$$

If the left-hand term is $1$ for some $k$, then all the terms must be equal to $1$. But the equation $\|A+B\|=2$ holds iff there is a sequence of unit vectors $x_n$ such that  $$2\leftarrow\|(A+B)x_n\|\le\|Ax_n\|+\|Bx_n\|\le2$$ Since $Ax_n$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^m$, it must have some convergent subsequence, $Ax_{n_i}\to y$. Let $f:=A^{-1}y$, so that $x_{n_i}\to f$, and thus $\|f\|=1$, $Bx_{n_i}\to Bf$, etc. The above set of inequalities now become, for the convergent subsequence, $$\|(A+B)f\|=\|Af\|+\|Bf\|=2$$ But as the question observes, this can only hold iff $Af=\lambda Bf$. It thus follows that $$ABf=\lambda B^2f=BAf$$ and so also the rest of the equations.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, shouldn't $\lambda =1$ ? and what is the rule of finite-dimensional condition?

Comment: Yes, $\lambda=1$ (but that fact is not used). Finite dimensionality is used when concluding that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. This is not true in general.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @ks1 You're welcome!

Comment: why the norm of $f$ is $1$?

Comment: @rose Because $\|x_i\|=1$.

Comment: @Chrystomath  I see $A^2 f=A(Af)=ABf$ and $B^2 f=B(Bf)=BAf$ but how $ABf=B^2 f$? Sorry for asking trivial questions with respect to you! Thanks.

Comment: @rose You need a small modification. Since $\|(A+B)^2f\|=\|A^2f\|+\|ABf\|+\|BAf\|+\|B^2f\|$, it follows that all the vectors are equal.